# Determine which projects use my Nuget package on Github?

Tags: c#, github, nuget

I've got a few Nuget packages that are SDKs for third-party APIs. Now, their download count is in the low thousands, but I know a large proportion of that is going to be from my CI/CD pipelines and me doing nuget restores whilst developing and whatnot.

So, I'd like to know if anyone is actually using my projects. It's not the end of the world if not, because I made them because I needed them, but it'd be good to know if I've helped someone.

Is there any way to reliably establish if any projects are consuming my nuget package, assuming that these are published publicly on Github? The best I can think of is just googling the name of my package but that's not proving very fruitful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Github itself might work. Maybe there is a good method around, but this is the best I could find get in my three minutes test.

https://github.com/search?l=XML&q=RestSharp.105&type=Code

https://github.com/search?l=XML&q=Hypermedia.Core&type=Code

https://github.com/search?l=XML&q=DiscosWebSdk&type=code

Is way less than perfect, but better than Google for the matter at hand.

Comment: Gotta give you some props for stalking my Github to pick up a package of mine to use as an example

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to reliably establish if any projects are consuming my nuget package?

The closest would be, in [`nuget.org/packages`](https://www.nuget.org/packages), the [**`Used By`**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json#usedby-body-tab) section which lists:

- NuGet packages that depend on xxx,
- GitHub repositories that depend on xxx.

Comment: Huh, I'd never noticed that before despite my years on nuget... It can't be particularly reliable though since it doesn't list my projects that I know depend on these packages

Comment: @ScottishTapWater But did you [publish your package to Nuget.org](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/nuget-org/publish-a-package)?

Comment: Yup, they're on Nuget